# Error in EC2 instance creation

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create an ec2 instance from my java code. If I use the the image id provided by Amazon as default images, it works.

For Example,the following code works

```
runInstancesRequest.withImageId("ami-37501207")
                    .withInstanceType("t1.micro").withMinCount(1)
                    .withMaxCount(1).withKeyName("yarn-research-aws");
RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = 
                      amazonEC2Client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
```

But, If I use my user defined image where I already installed Java and made a few changes, it gives me an error.

```
withImageId("ami-6fc1965f")
```

The above image id gives me the following error

```
Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type.
```

How will I do this?

Comment: Does your instance have a virtualization type of `hvm`?

Comment: @chrylis Yes, the virtualization type is HVM. But I am not sure how to change it.

Comment: Your image is HVM. You can use this on t2 instances within VPC, but not on previous generation instance types.